# What is the best Socket.io alternative in AWS serverless

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm building a custom serverless chat on AWS.
I want to use WebSockets for updating the messages.
I found that Socket.io is amazing for what I need and it also supports heartbeat as fallback if WebSockets does not work.

My problem with Socket.io is that is does not have server for AWS ApiGateway.

Is there any library that will replace Socket.io for me on serverless?

Comment: On Dec 2018, AWS announced the new WebSocket API in API Gateway. It's 100% serverless and AWS has an example on how to build a chat application https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway/

Comment: I know about that one, but it hurts to use it. For example I need to implement fallback hartbeat myself, take care of sessions in database, etc.